# Highcharts/highstocks Javascript from CSV file

Tags: javascript, csv, highcharts

I want a highstocks chart that can plot multiple streams from CSV files. My csv data looks like:

```
TIMESTAMP,DATA
2013-07-25 17:52:13.490,98425702
2013-07-25 17:52:34.840,382307
2013-07-25 17:52:55.900,380769
2013-07-25 17:54:37.380,500000
2013-07-25 17:54:47.910,98360155
2013-07-25 17:54:58.440,430000
2013-07-25 17:55:08.970,282307
2013-07-26 19:46:30.950,116923
```

Javascript in my index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
// Create the chart
$(function() {
    var magx = [];
    $.get('magx-11.csv', function(csv1) {
        var lines = csv1.split('\n');
        for (i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {
            var elements = lines.split(',');
            for (j=0; j<lines.length; j++) {
                magx.push([ elements[j] ])
            }
        }
        console.log(magx);
    });

    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Data'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Mag X',
            data: magx,
        }]
    });

});
</script>
```

With:

```
<body>
    <div id="container" style="width: 1200px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"</div>
</body>
```

So, I'm trying first figure how I need to parse the data. I've seen various references on splitting for new line, and then on the ',' delimiter. But from logging output, I don't think the data is being passed into the next function that I would like some help with please.

This has little effect too:

```
magx.push([ parseFloat(elements[j])
```

I would like to be able to extend this for multiple csv files too.

(I'm ignoring the incorrect datetime handling there, for now).

I've already seen: [Reading data from CSV with highstock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17243650/reading-data-from-csv-with-highstock) and [Highchart from CSV file with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26779758/highchart-from-csv-file-with-javascript). Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Replace these lines for (j=0; j<lines.length; j++) {
                magx.push([ elements[j] ])
            } with 
                magx.push(parseFloat(elements[1]) and let me know if works.

Comment: No luck I'm afraid. Got this in the debug console in Safari:
    TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'lines.split(',')')

Comment: In the line: var elements = lines.split(','); you should refer to index of line. As a result should be: var elements = lines[i].split(','); Next clue is that highcharts should be initialised in $.get callback, instead of out of them, as you have.

Comment: Oh. OK - I'll try all those parts. I will add a 'var chart = ...' to initialise. Unsure what this looks like for highstocks (not highcharts) but I'm sure I'll get it. Many thanks again - I'll post when I've got something worth showing.

Comment: OK. I've got it mostly going now - see answer. I now need to convert this to a format where multiple csv's can be parsed to the same chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trick was to investigate the JSON formats, then the Data.parse() formats. Documentation eh?

Also have "Highcharts error #15: http://www.highcharts.com/errors/15
highstock.js:13:195". My data is date-ordered, isn't that good enough?

Now need to convert this to multiple csv's per chart now.

```
$(function() {

    var magx = [];

    $.get('stuff.csv', function(csv1) {

                var lines = csv1.split('\n');

                $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
                       var items = line.split(',');

                       if(lineNo > 0) {
                            var ds1 = items[0].split(' ');
                                magx.push( [ Date.parse(ds1[0] + "T" + ds1[1]) , parseFloat(items[1]) ] );
                       };
                });

                var options = {

                xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime'
                },

                exporting: {
                enabled: true
                },

                series: [{
                         name: 'Data 1',
                         data: magx
                         }]

                };

                var chart = $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', options);

            });

          });
```

Comment: I advice you to avoid using Date.parse() because this not working in FF / IE. Better is using Date.UTC();